# C# Don't display filter extensions in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have multiple extensions in the Filter property of OpenFileDialog. Is possible to hide the extensions and show only the description?

Sample:

```
dialog.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpg; many image file extensions here"
```

I want to show only the text: "Image files" in the file type combo box because the extension string is very long. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
    dialog.Filter = "All Supported Audio | *.mp3; *.wma | MP3s | *.mp3 | WMAs | *.wma";
    dialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false; //using FileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false it will display the old XP sytle dialog box, which then displays correctly
    dialog.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Not a very good trade-off IMO... getting an older, ghetto-style OpenFileDialog or deal with the long list of file extensions. There should be a better way for Windows 7/8/10+

Answer (score 5):

This

```
dialog.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp)|*.bmp;*.jpg"
```

will only display "Image files (*.bmp)" in the combo box while still showing files with all the specified extensions.

Or you could do

```
dialog.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp;...)|*.bmp;*.jpg"
```

to indicate that it looks for files with extension bmp and some other extensions.

This might depend on the OS. I tested with Windows 7.

Comment: The only decent answer; it's a small trade-off to put something like (*.bmp) or (*.bmp; ...) in the first part of the filter instead of having to accept an XP-style dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It should work exactly as you wrote in your question:

```
dialog.Filter = "Image files|*.bmp;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. At least Windows 7 (and probably also Vista) automatically appends "`(*.bmp;*.jpg;other extensions)`" to the displayed text.

Comment: Oh, ok - that's not something the documentation states... It also wasn't the case on XP, so: sorry if I got it wrong :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple, you know. See the following code snippet. It will run perfectly. You can define more file-types like this way.

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|BMP Files(*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIF Files(*.gif)|*.gif|TIFF Files(*.tiff)|*.tiff|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
```

There are two parts in the `Filter` property. "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg" means the dropdown for selecting file-types will show `"JPG Files(*.jpg)"` and the filter will happen against the next part of pipe character i.e. `*.jpg`.

**Note:** *Never use any space after `*.jpg` or be it any other file-type. If used, it cannot filter your desired file-type.*

.

Comment: That wasn't the OP's question.